# multiple children for a supervisor

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp

I am a totally beginner in elixir, then I tried (inspired by the examples of programming elixir book) to create a **supervisor that can have several children of the same type**. I got the error

```
{:error, {{:EXIT, {{:badmatch, {:error,  {:already_started,#PID<0.122.0>}}},...
```

Maybe I misunderstand the usage of a supervisor and have to create a supervisor for each process.

Can anyone explain me the right usage of supervisors in this case ?

Comment: Can you also include the code you tried that threw that error?

Comment: Also look into `simple_one_for_one` type of supervisors, they can have one child defined, but spawn several of them dynamically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(I don't do Elixir, so this all uses Erlang syntax)

> create a supervisor that can have several children of the same type

Supervisors don't care about the "type" (in the sense you're using it) of the children. The child spec contains an `id`, a `start` function, and a few other things which aren't relevant to your question.

Provided the `id` is different, you can use the same `start` function for multiple children.

Where I suspect you're having difficulty is that your child has a *name*. That is: in your `init` function, you've called `gen_server:start_link/4`, passing something like `{local, ?MODULE}`. These processes all attempt to register with the same name, so you get the `already_started` error.

Comment: you were right, I tried to override the name in worker creation which does not seems to work. Thank you so much :)